# Proof by induction.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction

I have to prove two statements by induction but I really don't know how!
Could somebody give me some advice?

> 1) $\left(\begin{array}{c} -\frac{1}{2}
>  \\ n \end{array}\right) = \Large{(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}} \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $
>
> 2) $\left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{2}
>  \\ n \end{array}\right) = \Large{(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n)!!}} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}-{1} $

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by induction?

Comment: What is the meaning of $!!$ symbol?

Comment: @kumar see this link on the double factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: !! is the double factorial https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial . Yes, i'm familiar with proof by induction but i don't know how to do the inductive step of both. I  assumed that they holds for every k lesser than n and then i tried to prove the two statements for n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the binomial coefficient is:
$$
{\alpha\choose n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n+1)}{n!}
$$
From this definition, it is clear that
$$
{\alpha\choose n+1}=\frac{\alpha-n}{n+1}{\alpha\choose n}
$$
For $\alpha=-1/2$, this gives
$$
{-1/2\choose n+1}=\frac{-1/2-n}{n+1}{-1/2\choose n}=-\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}{-1/2\choose n}
$$
By the induction hypothesis:
$$
-\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}{-1/2\choose n}=-\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}(-1)^n\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n+2)!!}
$$
This completes the induction step and thus proves the formula $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
The second exercise proceeds completely analogously.